# ASP.NET Model binding One to Many + AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model with a one-to-many relationship kinda similar to this:

```
public class people
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public sting name { get; set; }
   public virtual stuff things { get; set; }
}
public class stuff
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public int thingType { get; set; }
}
```

I now need to be able to create and edit "stuff" for the person I am currently editing on my "editPeople" page.  I'm using AJAX to create JQuery UI Dialog box for the stuff edit/create form, and then I post it back to the server to create a bunch of hidden fields so I can actually save this data later.

I'm concerned that these hidden fields would be named in a way that such that when I post my peopleEdit back to the controller, the Model binding won't properly convert the "stuff" that I have created/edited.  Am I doing this wrong/Is there a better method?  Am I forced into creating a custom model binder?

Answer (score 0):

In my aproach would be if a people can have many stuff and you want to use ajax you can create a partial view to edit the stuff you would send the stuff object from people to the patial view action and run partial view action on the ajax call.

Comment: My objective is not to save it to the database until the original form (the people form) is submitted.

Comment: the save it in the temdata

Answer (score 0):

You may consider a javascript framework like Angular.js or Knockout.js to handle the data binding on the client.  Then on submit, you can attach a function and the framework would provide you with the values on the model which you can submit to your server via AJAX.